# fp-ts/typescript avoid nested pipes

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

How can I avoid nested pipes when using fp-ts in typescript? Do notation? Here's an example of nested pipe I want to avoid

```
  pipe(
  userId,
  O.fold(
    () => setUser('No user found'),
    (uId: string) => {
      fetchUser(uId).then((response: Either<NonEmptyArray<string>, User>) => {
        pipe(
          response,
          E.fold(
            () => setUser('Unable to fetch user'),
            (user: User) => setUser(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2))
          )
        );
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to delay `fold` as long as possible to avoid unnecessary nesting.

Algebraic effects can be composed without needing to know, if a value is existent or an operation has failed.

For example, a `TaskEither` transformed with [`chain`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/TaskEither.ts.html#chain)  will keep the first error, if no user has been found. Otherwise, it contains either the `fetchUser` error or the `User` data in success case.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-62353956-fp-ts-pmhif)

```
import { pipeable as P, option as O, taskEither as TE, nonEmptyArray as NA } from "fp-ts";

type User = { name: string };

// global state (side effect)
let user: string | undefined = undefined;
const setUser = (usr: string) => (user = usr);

// given input
const userId: O.Option<string> = O.some("Arun");

const fetchUser: (uid: string) => TE.TaskEither<NA.NonEmptyArray<string>, User> = uid =>
  TE.taskEither.of({ name: "Arun" });
  // An error case would be: TE.left(NA.of("Unable to fetch user"))  

const res = P.pipe(
  userId,
  TE.fromOption(() => NA.of("No user found")),
  TE.chain(fetchUser),
  TE.map(user => JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)),
  TE.fold( // we fold at the very end before applying the effect
    err => TE.taskEither.fromIO(() => { setUser(err[0]); }),
    user => TE.taskEither.fromIO(() => { setUser(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)); })
  ),
  TE.chain(() => TE.taskEither.fromIO(() => { console.log(user); }))
);

// run the effect
res();
```

PS: I assumed here, your `fetchUser` is an async operation, which creates `TaskEither`. You can switch it back to `Either`, if needed.

Comment: `chain` takes the computed value from previous sequence in pipe. Is that right?

Comment: yes, in above case `TE.chain(fetchUser)` resolves to a function that takes the `TaskEither` from previous pipe segment and returns a new transformed one.